# How do I run two main functions in Xcode simultaneously using fork()

Tags: c++, xcode, unix, compilation, fork

I'm trying to run two different main functions in two separate processes using fork(). Each of the main functions is in a .cpp file. The first file is named client.cpp where am doing the forking, here is a brief code:

```
     File: client.cpp

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    //some code...

if (fork()) {
         if (execv("./server", NULL) != 0){
             cerr << " Failed to lunch the server" << endl;;
         }
     }
     else{

        //continue executing client.cpp
```

The other file is server.cpp, which has to be running on another process in order for getting client.cpp running, otherwise client.cpp would pause till it sees server.cpp running.

The whole program is very simple, the client send some request in string form, and then server reply to those request. The main function in server.cpp has to be fired before the main function in client.cpp

I normally compile all of the files using makefile, then open two separate terminal windows and run ./client in one window, and ./server in the other one, and it would work just fine. However, I just don't know how to do the same thing using Xcode, so I can easily debug it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `fork()` and the subsequent `if` has a problem.  The return value from `fork()` is -1 on failure else the parent return value is the PID of the newly forked child, and the child process return result is 0.

This test:

```cpp
if (fork()){ ...
```

will *succeed* if `fork` fails (non-zero return).